# Почему элементы перекрывают header?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть вёрстка лендинга(делаю чисто для практики). Встретился с такой проблемой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Некоторые элементы находятся поверх данного header'а. Как сделать чтобы `div` с header'ом находились выше всех остальных элементов?

Думаю, ошибка где-то в css. Код могу скинуть(в комменты отпишитесь нужен или нет), но там много библиотек, без которых ничего работать не будет. И к томуже, css разбит на несколько файлов, дабы не запутаться какой из них относится к какому элементу и библиотеке.

Comment: Сделайте свойство z-index header'а больше всех остальных блоков на сайте.

Comment: @МаксимЛевицкий, спасибо большое) Помогло)

Comment: Сделайте ответ, который я смогу принять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте свойство z-index селектора header больше, чем у остальных блоков на сайте.
К примеру:

```
header {
  z-index: 99999;
}
```